# How to convert UTC dates that are stored in MSSMS to local time in my program when they are called

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, utc, localtime

So this Publish time is a datetime in UTC that is retrieved from my database, it is currently in UTC and I need to change it to local time and then display the local time on my LineChartDataSet

[image]

Comment: Remind me what "MSSMS" is, please?

Comment: @Wyck i think he meant to say SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), but what he meant was 'sql server'.

Comment: Post your code as *text* especially the code that retrieves the data. Dates loaded from a database are `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`. You'll have to change their type to `UTC` before you can convert them to local time. A better idea would be to use `datetimeoffset` instead of `datetime` with an assumed offset. You'd avoid the need for such conversions

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You don't "store" data in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio though, @sommmen , it's just an IDE like application.

Answer (score 2):

You can transform UTC dates to other timezone equivalents using a `TimeZoneInfo` instance.

You can get the local timezone by using `TimeZoneInfo.Local`.

Put together:

```
var yourTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
var localDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, yourTimeZone);
```

Pick another timezone to have your chart work for people in other regions, even on the same computer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToLocalTime()`

> Converts the value of the current DateTime object to local time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime?view=net-6.0

That is; it will translate the value to the local datetime of the server server. If all your users and the server are set to the same timezone, this works, else take a look at the other answer.

You need `DateTime.SpecifyKind` because the date time coming from EF core has a Kind of `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, so we need to specify that the datetime is UTC before converting to local time.

Comment: That's not enough. Dates loaded from a database are `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`. The `datetime` type doesn't have any UTC flags and the database driver won't guess. The Kind would have to change to `UTC` before it can be converted to `Local`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ran a little test and you're right. I normally use DateTimeOffset for TZ sensitive columns so it slipped my mind.